# Xamarin Forms: Azure AD B2C using MSAL: Set Client Id through code

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to use MSAL for Azure AD B2C authentication in Xamarin forms.
I have followed this tutorial:
[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-xamarin-forms/)

But this asks to set the client id in Intent Filter. What if i am building a product and it needs to be distributed to more then one customer through public store?

Is there any way we can set the client ID programmatically?
Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set client ID programmatically.

If you want your customer from different tenants to use your B2C project, you just need to configure your Azure AD app as multi-tenant.

Just like the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-preview#register-a-web-application) you shared mentions:

> Select Accounts in any organizational directory or any identity
>   provider.

And then you could [Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom?tabs=applications). Then customer will be able to log into your project with their own credentials.

**In fact**, you don't even need to configure sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies. Customers could sign up to your B2C tenant to use your product. This is exactly how B2C works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Allen.
My scenario is where every customer has their own B2C setup but the App is single and can be downloaded from App Store or Play Store.  In this case, hard coding client Id in the app will limit us to one customer.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The client id used in the `IntentFilter` on that particular tutorial is for the `DataScheme` which needs to be unique, so AAD knows where to redirect after the authentication screen. You could use a different value if you want. It is common to use the reverse-DNS for that field (as for the app package).

In other words, `clientId` is not mandatory for that field.